# Blank screen issue on localhost site when zend_extension for xdebug is loaded?  (Win 7, Apache 2.2, cakePHP 1.2)

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2, xdebug, cakephp-1.2

In a fairly large e-commerce site running on my localHost for testing, I get blank screens when the zend_extension for xdebug is loaded in the `.../php/extensions/` directory and `zend_extension = C:/UniServer/usr/local/php/extensions/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll` is set in php.ini. Without it, the site works fine.

When I run a simple blog site developed under cakePHP 1.3 it works fine even with the zend_extension loaded.

My failing config is:

```
Windows 7; Apache 2.2.17; PHP 5.3.5; cakePHP version 1.2.1.8004; php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll.
```

Maybe the problem is caused by the fact that I am running a complicated site, or by the fact that I am using cakePHP 1.2.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Stephen Ippolito

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems to be a xDebug version problem. To fix it I used the old xDebug (php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll) and it started to work fine.
NOTE: I was trying to test a Magento 1.7.1 site with the last wamp version.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had to be sure to get the "TS" version of xdebug, that took be a bit to figure out as well.

Answer (score 1):

My local environment:  WampServer 2.2E 64bit (Apache 2.2.22 – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.3.13 XDebug 2.1.2 XDC 1.5 PhpMyadmin 3.4.10.1 SQLBuddy 1.3.3 webGrind 1.0)

When I first installed, I assumed everything works fine.  But when i performed my first debug, a blank loaded everytime I debugged.  I know xdebug loaded since i was able to debug if I had a previous screen loaded and performing a submission.  After using the wizard below and downloading the correct version, my xdebug worked.

Go here:
http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Answer (score 0):

Apache should be keeping an error log. Check what it says when you get the blank screen. Usually a blank screen means there was a 500 error.

Since it's happening when you load a particular extension it's likely that PHP is unable to load that extension for some reason.

If you don't know where the error log is, look for the `ErrorLog` directive in your Apache configuration. That should give you the path to the file (might be relative to the Apache config path)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it does not help.  There is no corresponding error in the Apache error log.  Also, the failure occurs when I try to access the site, not when I start Apache.  I can even follow the code in the debugger for a while using single step and breakpoints.  However, there is an enormous amount of code.  It is impractical to single step to see where it goes.  When I let it run, it comes back with a blank screen and blank page source.

Comment: Apache should be logging errors that occur when the PHP script fails for any reason. Check that error_logging is turned on in php.ini and if you're using VirtualHost check to see if your host has it's own log.